# Cloud Firestore query with Variable in Where clause isn't working node

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nest

I'm trying to integrate firestore into my nestjs app. When i try to retrieve data from firestore using `where` clause without variable(hardcoded value) i was able to retrieve data but when i use a variable i just receive empty array.

Here is the code i try to retrieve data from firestore.

```
  async getUserPosts(userId: number): Promise<PostsDocument[]> {
    this.logger.log(`Getting posts for user with ID: ${userId}`);
    const snapshot = await this.postsCollection
       .where('userId', '==', userId)
       .get();
    const posts: PostsDocument[] = [];
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       this.logger.debug(`Found post: ${doc.id}`);
       posts.push(doc.data());
     });
     return posts;
  }
```

When i replace `userId` variable in where clause with 1 i was receiving data but this doesn't work.

`[Nest] 1854  - 07/31/2022, 10:09:58 AM     LOG [PostsService] Getting posts for user with ID: 1`

I did verify that userId is received based on above log.

this is my controller code

```
  @Get()
  getUserPosts(@Query() query: { userId: number }) {
    if (query.userId) {
        return this.postsService.getUserPosts(query.userId);
    } else {
        return this.postsService.getPosts();
    }
  }
```

[image: firestore console document screenshot]
firebase console document screenshot for `.collection("posts") .where("userId", "==", 1)`

[image: VsCode Debug view]

Comment: Do you get any error (You should probably add a `catch()`block)? Are you sure you get the correct value for `this.postsCollection`. Which SDK and version are you using?

Comment: I did try adding try catch i don't see any error logged. 
Regarding postsCollection i guess i have right collection because i was receiving data on hardcoded value.
SDK name and version=> "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1",

Comment: Can you try to log the size of the returned `QuerySnapshot` with `this.logger.log(snapshot.size);` after the call to the `get()`method?

Comment: As Renaud hinted already, the code you have in your first fragment looks fine at first glance, so the problem is likely either in some other piece of the code or in the data. I recommend stepping through the code line-by-line in a debugger and inspecting each variable on each line, until you find one that doesn't match your expectations. If that doesn't help you solve it, can you edit your question to show a screenshot of a document you expect to be returned?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec i'm just receiving size 0. when i use parameter, replacing with hardcoded number returns 10

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I'm new to firebase is there any way to check debug logs on firestore/google cloud to check if its even receiving value sent through variable.

Comment: No you cannot read Firestore logs. But if you get 0 docs in the QuerySnapshot it is because your query returns 0 documents. Are you 100% sure the value of `userId` is correct? Can you share a screenshot of the Firestore console, showing the document?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec added firestore console document screenshot, also added debug view which shows userId as 1 and snapshot size as 0

Comment: Actually thats an public project on github in case you want to check.

https://github.com/kanakamedala-rajesh/basic-server/blob/master/src/posts/posts.service.ts#L73

Comment: What I see in the screenshot at the bottom of your question is `userId: '1'`. If you query with a string while the field is of type number, you'll get an empty `QuerySnapshot`!

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec, I think thats the issue but not sure why thats happening i did check userID type and it shows as string even when i declared that as number. I'll try and see if i can fix it any other way and post a solution here. Thanks once again

Comment: If you don't mind I'll also write an answer with this finding, and you may upvote it if you think the different comments and "research" helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the [`where()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#where) method in order to build a [`Query`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html) it is very important that the value passed as third parameter **is of the same type** than the field declared as first parameter.

As shown in the comments under your question, after some debugging it appeared that you were passing a string as field value for a field that is of type number. Hence the empty `QuerySnapshot`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @Renaud Tarnec and @Frank van Puffelen for helping out.

Issue: typescript number variable considered as string in `while` clause.

Fix: passing userId as `Number(userID)` instead of userId fixed issue

```
const snapshot = await this.postsCollection
      .where('userId', '==', Number(userId))
      .get();
```